# How to start linux systems & device drivers programming

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am android application developer. I want to gain knowledge of linux systems & device drivers programing also. Where should I start?? Can any one suggest some books or links to tutorials...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are not a lot of literature about AOSP programming. You should look for Embedded Android. But I can recommend you the following links:

1. [Android porting guide](http://hsc.com/Portals/0/Uploads/Articles/Android-Porting-on-Embedded-Platform_v2_0633850602027036930.pdf).
2. ["Embedded Android"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do) book.
3. [The presentation of the same author](https://events.linuxfoundation.org/slides/2011/abs/abs2011_yaghmour_porting.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

LDD 3

https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

CS:APP2e

http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/

Answer (score 2):

`Professional Linux kernel architecture` by `Maurer Wolfgang` is an excellent book.